# Diagonalization of a Matrices Represent Change of Basis.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, quantum-mechanics, similar-matrices

In our examination of Mathematical Physics course, a question came which had a matrix written in the standard basis for a 2 by 2 matrix. Now he changed the basis of the given matrix and told us to write the new matrix in terms of these new basis.

I gave it a try by solving and finding the eigenvalues of the matrix (whom to be written in new basis) and now my doubt arises that should i ow use their eigenvectors or what. and if i use them, what to do next.

I tried looking for answers and found a YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/s4c5LQ5a4ek?t=530), but was unable to catch up.

I need to clear this doubt as my professor said it will play a huge role in Quantum Mechanics that denationalization of matrices or similarity transformation represent change of basis.

Edit- I know the 3 important properties of matrices to be similar. Being a Physics student, would appreciate every possible explanation of it.

Comment: Use the eigenvectors as the column vectors of the change-of-basis matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the precise data, but some generalities can be say.

If your initial matrix is, say $A$ and the matrix of the change of basis is $B$ then the version of $A$ in this new basis is $B^{-1}AB$.

If you want to diagonalize (or almost diagonalize) $A$ then choosing the eigenvectors of $A$ as the basis change with matrix $C$, then $C^{-1}AC$ would be diagonal or almost diagonal.

Edit: Take $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\2&5\end{array}\right]$ and the basis change:
$$b_1=2e_1+3e_2,$$
$$b_2=2e_1-3e_2,$$
then $B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&2\\3&-3\end{array}\right]$
and $B^{-1}AB=\frac{1}{48}\left[\begin{array}{cc}7&11\\10&18\end{array}\right]$.

This can be interpreted as if $A$ determine a linear transformation
$\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ then $B^{-1}AB$ represents the very same transformation but after the basis change in both domain and codomain.

In the case you take eigenvectors from $A$ **any choice** of them will do the analogous effect but nearing to its diagonalization.

Comment: I got your point of A as a matrix in one basis and B matrix which was of B but in new basis. But in your 2nd line what is C here according to above statement.

Comment: my question is then, when we have eigenvalues, we have numerous amount of choices to choose eigenvectors and form, so does that mean if i choose new eigenvector, will my A matrix will also change for every different eigenvector because when i use spectral decomposition i always have same A matrix. Or i am doing something wrong and spectral decomposition means something else.

Comment: Can you explain it by taking a random matrix element of a 2 by 2 matrix and reedit your comment by showing what does A means and B here. would be very helpful for me

Comment: take a look https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition%7B%7B1%2C2%7D%2C%7B2%2C5%7D%7D

Comment: $C$ would be the matrix with the components of any of the eigenvectors (or generalized eigenvector) of $A$, that one must take as a change of basis.